# Update multiple cart items quantity. Spring Boot - Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need help with updating a "quantity" of Product in my cart from a submit button, I'm clueless. I have successfully added the Product on the Carts page, I have an Update Button that should update the new quantity input value on the UI, just help and tips with updating the List of Cart Items when changes are been made to the quantity of the individual items. Thanks

```
//Iterating over the cartItems to be displayed on the carts page

    <tr th:each="cartItem : ${cart.cartItems}">
                            
                            <td class="product-name">
                                <h2 class="h5 text-black" th:text="${cartItem.product.productName}">Polo Shirt</h2>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group mb-3"  style="max-width: 120px;">
                                    
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control quantity text-center" th:value="${cartItem.quantity}" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                                    
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td th:text="${'₦' + #numbers.formatDecimal(cartItem.price, 0, 'COMMA', 0, 'POINT')}"></td>
                            <td><a th:href="${'/cart/removeCartItem/' + cartItem.cartItemId}" class="btn btn-primary height-auto btn-sm">X</a></td>
                        </tr>
    
//The update button
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Update Cart</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to increment amount of specific items in your cart and reflect this change on UI?